unreal tenses reported speech
I have found in my book that unreal tenses after wish / if only, would rather / would sooner, it's (high) time and as if / as though do not change in indirect speech. For instance "I would rather you were smarter" once reported stays the same " he said he would rather she was smarter". My question is: Do "would prefer, prefer, and used to" also belong to that group or after them we backshift we think that the info is no longer true?

"I would prefer to do that". "She said she would prefer to do that." Whether or not it's still true is irrelevant; it was her preference at the time of speaking.

BTW, see also subjunctive mood or tense.
